# Symfony lazy-loading form choices

Tags: symfony6

I'm trying to implement choice list that renders after the submitted data has been set. Seems that choice_loader (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-loader) should be the answer but I cannot get it working... Below is modified example from the manual:

```
# contoller
    // $filter is model fed into form and is empty at this point
    $form = $this->createForm(PersonFilterType::class, $filter, ['finder' => $personFinder]);

# form builder
    $builder->add('loaded_choices', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choice_loader' => new CallbackChoiceLoader(static function (): array {
            return StaticClass::getConstants(); <-- this is called on form creating ($this->createForm)...
        }),
    ]);
```

The CallbackChoiceLoader's callback argument is executed on form building (ie when person filter is empty, without submitted data). I need it to be called later.